# Why isn't this click handler fadeToggle code working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to fade in div elements but for some reason every time I preview my script code it just displays it and doesn't run it

my script code is -

```
 <script>
$("#t<?php echo $pNumber ?>").click(function() {
$("#b.<?php echo $pNumber ?>").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
</script>
```

the PHP variable is used for changing div id's would this be causing a problem?

Thanks,

UPDATE -

example html this is for one of the div's (the id is incremented)

```
  <div id="t1">Carl Froch 'fitter than ever' for Andre Ward Showtime Super Six       fight</div>
  <div id="b1"><p>Carl Froch gives Andre Ward seven years but no encouragement to      believe their fight  on Saturday night is a war of the ages.</p><p>The 34-year-old WBC    champion from Nottingham rarely strays far from the 12-stone limit of his division and is     hard o...<p><a href=http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/2011/dec/14/carl-froch-andre-  ward-showtime-super-six>Click here for full article</a></p>   </div  <script>
  $("#t1").click(function() {
  $("#b1").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  });
 </script>
```

JB

Comment: Can you make a stripped-down sample of your HTML, and add it to the question?  It is hard to answer this definitively without it.

Comment: Seems like it is working to me.  Though the code you have before expansion is *not* the same as the code after expansion.  Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your element selectors:

- You're including the `$pNumber` as part of the `t`'s `id` for the click event
- You're including the `$pNumber` as part of the `b`'s *`class`* for the `fadeToggle`

To fix this, do one of these:

- Add a dot to the `#t` selector, to make it select based on `class`
- Remove the dot from the `#b` selector, to make it select based on `id`

See [this fiddle before removing the `.`](http://jsfiddle.net/eaJMz/):

```
$("#t1").click(function() {
    $("#b.1").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

See [this fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuPBG/):

```
$("#t1").click(function() {
    $("#b1").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```